# Generating new output for each row in a csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with some data in it,

`match_type keyword         campaign                group
exact       find a key      Non-Branded             Find key - Exact
phrase      key physicians  Branded System (key)    key Brand (Acronyn) - Phrase
phrase      key locations   Branded System (key)    key Brand (Acronyn) - Phrase`

I want to loop through each row and for each `match_type` generate new output, like so,

`exact = pd.DataFrame()
 phrase = pd.DataFrame()`

```
for x in match_type:
        if x == 'exact':
            exact['Match type'] = pd.np.where(pos.Match_type.str.contains('exact'), 'exact',
                                  pd.np.where(pos.Match_type.str.contains('phrase'), 'negative exact', 'negative exact'))

            exact['Keyword'] = pd.np.where(pos.Search_term.str.contains('physicians'), 'key physicians',
                               pd.np.where(pos.Search_term.str.contains('locations'), 'key locations',
                               pd.np.where(pos.Search_term.str.contains('find'), 'find a key', 'None')))

            exact['Campaign'] = pd.np.where(pos.Campaign.str.contains('Branded'), 'Branded System (key)',
                                pd.np.where(pos.Campaign.str.contains('Non-Branded'), 'Non-Branded Brand', 'None'))

            exact['Ad_Group'] = pd.np.where(pos.Ad_group.str.contains('- Phrase'), 'key Brand (Acronyn) - Phrase',
                                pd.np.where(pos.Ad_group.str.contains('- Exact'), 'Find key - Exact', 'None'))          

        elif x == 'phrase':
            phrase['Match type'] = pd.np.where(pos.Match_type.str.contains('exact'), 'negative phrase',
                                   pd.np.where(pos.Match_type.str.contains('phrase'), 'phrase', 'negative phrase'))

            phrase['Keyword'] = pd.np.where(pos.Search_term.str.contains('physicians'), 'key physicians',
                                pd.np.where(pos.Search_term.str.contains('locations'), 'key locations',
                                pd.np.where(pos.Search_term.str.contains('find'), 'find a key', 'None')))

            phrase['Campaign'] = pd.np.where(pos.Campaign.str.contains('Branded'), 'Branded System (key)',
                                 pd.np.where(pos.Campaign.str.contains('Non-Branded'), 'Non-Branded Brand', 'None'))

            phrase['Ad_Group'] = pd.np.where(pos.Ad_group.str.contains('- Phrase'), 'key Brand (Acronyn) - Phrase',
                                 pd.np.where(pos.Ad_group.str.contains('- Exact'), 'Find key - Exact', 'None'))
```

Now this works, it loops through each row and transforms the data to what the desired output should be. Which looks like,

```
Match type      Keyword         Campaign                Ad_Group
negative exact  key physicians  Branded System (key)    key Brand (Acronyn) - Phrase
negative exact  key locations   Branded System (key)    key Brand (Acronyn) - Phrase
exact           find a key      Non-Branded             Find key - Exact
phrase          key physicians  Branded System (key)    key Brand (Acronyn) - Phrase
phrase          key locations   Branded System (key)    key Brand (Acronyn) - Phrase
negative phrase find a key      Non-Branded             Find key - Exact
```

The trouble I am running into here is generalizing the code so it works for any csv with varying data in it. The `match_type` will stay the same but all of the other columns inputs can be different. I can't seem to find anything that will help me generalize this. Maybe because I am fairly new to programming

Example of varying data,

`match_type keyword              campaign              group
exact       other key            Non-Branded only      Other key - Exact
exact       key                  Branded               Brand - Exact
phrase      other key locations  System (key)          key Brand - Phrase
exact       key                  Branded               Brand - Exact
phrase      key locations only   System (key)          key Brand - Phrase`

Comment: Could you provide your input to get the result shown, and also an example about the variying data in the other csv?

Comment: @Ben.T , I have provided the input that gave me the results shown as well as an example of how the data can vary

Comment: ok, now what is the generalization asked. With your example, it seems that the dataframe `exact` you create is like your input dataframe (which seems to be named `pos`) except for the first column where the `phrase` is replaced by `negative exact`. Is the point of all your code to just repalce this? all the `np.where` are not necessary then, except for the first column?

Comment: by this I mean, if your point is just to create a datafame `exact` which is like your input except the first column where you actually change `phrase` to `negative exact`, you are going the complicated way :)

Comment: @Ben.T, ugh you're right. I'm doing it the complicated way lol. Instead of changing all of the columns I just change the `match_type` column and then leave the rest alone. I have no clue why I didn't think about that in the first place, smh. Thanks for the logical thinking help haha